# Can't Get Eclipse Watch Points To Work

Tags: eclipse

I can't get watch points to work in eclipse.  Here is what i've done, double clicked to the left of the variable intilization and now it says watchpoints for modify/access.  When I run in debug mode the eclipse debugger does not break when the variable is modified.  I don't have problems when setting line break points.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Right click** on your debugger and choose source look up then add selection on your project
Will work with you :)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, here's what I did:

```
    package dao;

public class Watchpoint {

    /* placed breakpoint here in Eclipse*/ private int i = 0;

    public void modif() {
        this.i = 3;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Watchpoint().modif();
    }
}
```

Having the above code in Eclipse Helios (Service Release 2), I've added a breakpoint on the "private int i=0; line (by double clicking to it's left). Then if I go into debug mode, in the Breakpoint tab (in upper right), I can select that watchpoint, and then I have the checkable options "Access" and "Modifications". If I check both and then debug the code, the debugger will halt at the line "this.i = 3;" inside the modif() method.

Comment: Can you please post that code, and tell where exactly you put the breakpoint/watchpoint?

Comment: Same problem, but I'm running Galileo--the "Access" and "Modifications" are not available.

Running on Android--does that make a difference?